# Grouping dates by months in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I group a array of dates to get a new array of objects with grouped dates by months in Javascript

I have:

```
const arr = [
Date Sat Dec 31 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
​Date Sun Jan 01 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
​Date Mon Jan 02 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
Date Tue Jan 31 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
​​Date Wed Feb 01 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
​​Date Thu Feb 02 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
​​Date Fri Feb 03 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
​​Date Sat Feb 04 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
​​Date Sun Feb 05 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
​​Date Mon Feb 06 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
​​Date Tue Feb 07 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
​​Date Wed Feb 08 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
​​Date Thu Feb 09 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
​​Date Fri Feb 10 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
]
```

And I want to get:

```
const nArr = [
{
 name: December,
 dates:[
        Date Sat Dec 31 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
       ]
},
{
 name: January,
 dates:[
​        Date Sun Jan 01 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
​        Date Mon Jan 02 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
        Date Tue Jan 31 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
       ]
}
....
]
```

I try to use array reducer, but I have problem with it

```
arr.reduce((acc, val) => {

        const d = new Date(val)
        let m = months[d.getMonth()]

        acc[m] = acc[m]
        acc[m].push(val)

        return acc

    }, [])
```

Thank you for help, I'm new in JS

Comment: Array reduce is the first step

Comment: I have tried

arr.reduce((acc, val) => {

        const d = new Date(val)
        let m = months[d.getMonth()]

        acc[m] = acc[m]
        acc[m].push(val)

        return acc

    }, [])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const dates = [new Date(), new Date()];
const months = [
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May", 
  "June",
  "July",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December"
];

const sortedDates: Array<{name: string, dates: Array<Date>}> = [];

dates.map(date => {
  const month = months[date.getMonth()];
  const monthObj = sortedDates.find(datesByMonth => datesByMonth.name === month)
  
  if (monthObj === undefined) {
    sortedDates.push({
      name: month,
      dates: [
        date
      ]
    })
    return;
  }

  monthObj.dates.push(date);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but this is how I would have solved it

```
    const arr = [
        new Date('Date Sat Dec 31 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time'),
        new Date('Date Sun Jan 01 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time'),
        new Date('Date Mon Jan 02 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time'),
        new Date('Date Tue Jan 31 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time'),
        new Date('Date Wed Feb 01 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time'),
        new Date('Date Thu Feb 02 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time'),
        new Date('Date Fri Feb 03 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time'),
        new Date('Date Sat Feb 04 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time'),
        new Date('Date Sun Feb 05 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time'),
        new Date('Date Mon Feb 06 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time'),
        new Date('Date Tue Feb 07 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time'),
        new Date('Date Wed Feb 08 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time'),
        new Date('Date Thu Feb 09 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time'),
        new Date('Date Fri Feb 10 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time'),
    ];

    let months = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var month = arr[i].getMonth();
        if (!months[month]) {
            months[month] = [];
        }
        months[month].push(arr[i]);
    }

    console.log(months);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the full month "name" by formatting the locale string with the `month:long` [option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Using_options).

```js
const toLongMonth = (date) =>
  date.toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'long' });

const groupBy = (arr, fn) => arr.reduce((acc, item) =>
  (month => ({
    ...acc,
    [month]: [ ...(acc[month] || []), item ]
  }))
  (fn(item)), {});

const groupByMonth = (dates) =>
  Object.entries(groupBy(dates, toLongMonth))
    .map(([name, dates]) => ({ name, dates }))

const dates = [
  new Date('Sat Dec 31 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)'),
  new Date('Sun Jan 01 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)'),
  new Date('Mon Jan 02 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)'),
  new Date('Tue Jan 31 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)'),
  new Date('Wed Feb 01 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)'),
  new Date('Thu Feb 02 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)'),
  new Date('Fri Feb 03 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)'),
  new Date('Sat Feb 04 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)'),
  new Date('Sun Feb 05 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)'),
  new Date('Mon Feb 06 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)'),
  new Date('Tue Feb 07 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)'),
  new Date('Wed Feb 08 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)'),
  new Date('Thu Feb 09 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)'),
  new Date('Fri Feb 10 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)')
];

console.log(groupByMonth(dates));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```